# component update doesn't see the latest var value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem about updating component. In the following snippet, I updated the value of an external var `userInfo` and a component state `isLoading` in `Promise.then()`. Due to the update of `isLoading`, the component is re-rendered as expected. However, the external var `userInfo` wasn't updated.  Any explanation? Thank you!

PS: If I make `userInfo` to be a state hook, the result is as expected and I can see the last `console.log` print out the updated value of `userInfo`.  But I still want to understand why an ordinary variable doesn't work.

```
export default function ProfilePage() {

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const userInfo = {};

  const _fetchData= () => {
    getUser()
      .then(async (basicInfo)=> {
        if (basicInfo.ok) {
          userInfo['basicInfo'] = await basicInfo.json();  
          console.log("In Promise.then, userInfo= %s", JSON.stringify(userInfo));
          setIsLoading(false);
        } else {
          throw new Error("failed to get basicInfo");
        }
      }).catch((err)=> console.log(`something wrong ${err}`));
    return ()=>{};
  }; // end _fetchData

  React.useEffect(_fetchData,[]);
  console.log("In ProfilePage, userInfo= %s", JSON.stringify(userInfo));
  return isLoading ? (<div> Loading</div>): (
    <div> Loaded </div>
  );
}
```

This is the `console.log` output:

```
18:02:28.233 In ProfilePage userInfo={}   #empty as expected. 
18:02:28.291 In Promise.then, userInfo={"basicInfo": {"user":"a"}} #userInfo has been updated 
18:02:28.292 In ProfilePage userInfo={}   #why not updated?
```

Comment: `userInfo` *also* needs to be in state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you call setIsLoading, ProfilePage component re-render which means const userInfo is initialized with empty object literal again. That's why it looks like not updated. There are some ways to handle this issue, the first one is define userInfo as state like you said, and the second is use useRef like below. React remembers value defined in the ways even though its component re-renders.

```
const userInfo = useRef({});
...
if (basicInfo.ok) {
          const basicInfo = await basicInfo.json();
          userInfo.current = {basicInfo };  
          setIsLoading(false);
        } else {
          throw new Error("failed to get basicInfo");
        }
```